# Django-filter won't display TreeNodeChoiceField (MPTT package) as tree choice field

Tags: django, django-filter, django-mptt

I have a `Category` MPTT model. I have a `Transaction` django model which has a `ForeignKey` assigned to `Category` model (field = 'category').
Using `django-filter` lib I'm trying to filter `Transactions` in a `ListView`. Everything works fine except the 'category' filter field appears as choice field with plain list of all categories instead of list with tree 'leveling'.

My FilterSet class:

```
class TransactionsListFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    """ Filters for Transaction list. """

    title = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="icontains", label="Transaction title")
    date_created = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(widget=RangeWidget(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    category = TreeNodeChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ["title", "category", "operation", "date_created"]
```

I was trying to add a TreeNodeChoiceField as I did the same in forms (there it works) but in FilterSet class don't make a trick. The dropdown choice field is still plain list without category leveling by subcategory.
Is there a way to make the choice list appears with as tree?